# "Backbone is not defined" error with Backbone 1.1.2 and RequireJS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I have just upgraded from Backbone 1.0 to Backbone 1.1.2.

I use requireJS and I use r.js to optimize the files for production.

In my non-optimized environment, everything works great.

However, after I use r.js to compress the files, I get the error "Backbone is not defined."

From my searches online this seems to have something to do with an AMD implementation that was introduced in Backbone 1.1.1.  The recommendation seems to be to set `wrapShim: true` (https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/issues/623)

However, I have tried this, and am still getting the same error.

Any suggestions as to how I can fix this?  Or should I just stick with the old version of backbone?

Comment: We had the same frustrating problem and we came to the conclusion that require.js just wasn't for use. We switched it out for browserify and a sturdy grunt build and that worked great. I have no solution, just wanted to share my experiences :)

Comment: did you try updating requirejs, which version are you using? https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/1249#issuecomment-41769955 it seems here it works with requirejs 2.1.11, almond backbone 1.1.2 and the wrapShim config property

Comment: @khattab - You are right, I was using an older version of requirejs.  I updated to the newer version and it worked properly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are using AMD or non-AMD version of Backbone. The way you should refer Backbone will change with that. Say if it is non-AMD version Backbone is available globally, in AMD version backbone reference will not be available globally, but wherever you define and require it.